# Kubernetes can't run container

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, kubectl, kubernetes-helm

Trying run container on Kubernetes, container don't start, fail with error:

```
Error: failed to start container "tbsp-dev-container":
Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error:
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:320: writing syncT run type caused
"write parent: broken pipe
```

Can you help me figure this out please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that you are base64 encoding all the secrets you are passing to the container.

Based on this [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52481) that might cause that error to trigger.